# Dynamically setting a divs font-size so div fills screen vertically

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

I have two rows of four divs each set up via `flexbox` to span the page horizontally. Thus the `width` of the divs is dynamic and always adapts to the window width.

The divs' height depends on their content, i.e. by the content's `font-size`. I would like to set up the `CSS` of the divs so that they always fill the window vertically, not by setting their `height` but by the `font-size` changing.

Is what I'm describing possible? See the fiddle below for the current setup of the page:

```css
.banner {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.flex {
 display: flex;
}

.row {
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;

 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: white;

 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="top" id="top">
  <div>
   <div class="flex row banner">
    <div class="box rotate-right">
     <p>
      1
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box rotate-left">
     <p>
      2
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box rotate-right">
     <p>
      3
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box rotate-left">
     <p>
      4
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
      
     <div class="flex row banner">
    <div class="box rotate-right">
     <p>
      5
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box rotate-left">
     <p>
      6
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box rotate-right">
     <p>
      7
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box rotate-left">
     <p>
      8
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>

   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to understand why you would want this. Now would be a good moment to pause and think if you need this for whatever project you are working on.

---

### Done?

If you still think you need this, here we go.

CSS has two size units that are dependent on the viewport's width and height, namely `vw` and `vh`. These are units on a scale of 1 to 100, 100 being whatever dimension you use. An example:

```
div {
    height: 100vh; /* 100vh = 100% of the viewport height */
    width: 50vw; /* 50vw = 50% of the viewport width */
}
```

The nice thing is that this can be used anywhere, unlike percentages, which have different meanings based on the property.

```
div {
    height: 100%; /* = 100% of parent element height */
    width: 100%; /* = 100% of parent element width */
    font-size: 100%; /* = 100% of parent element font size */
}

div {
    height: 100vw; /* = 100% of viewport height */
    width: 100vh; /* = 100% of viewport height */
    font-size: 100vh; /* = 100% of viewport height */
}
```

Here's the tedious part. From your question, I understand that you want text to fill up the height of the given element. Correct?

This now depends on the number of lines of text. My example is one with a  single line of text as this is what you've put in the question.

---

### Single-line text (from your example)

I set the `font-size` to `40vh`. Setting the `font-size` to `50vh` doesn't seem to work. However, a similar effect is acheieved by setting the height to `50vh` and leaving the font-size at `40vh`. The text scales with the box to (almost) fill it.

I have also removed the default margin from the body. I recommend you this whenever anything is fullscreen, because other wise, you'd have to take it into account.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 40vh;
  height: 50vh
}
```

```html
<div class="top" id="top">
  <div>
    <div class="flex row banner">
      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          1
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          2
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          3
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          4
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex row banner">
      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          5
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          6
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          7
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          8
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```